# How does laravel track a one-to-one relationship if i have not used the unique() method in my migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

This is a Laravel and SQL-related question. Basically if I want to create a one-to-one relationship in SQL i do it as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person
(
Pk_Person_Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(255),
EmailId VARCHAR(255),
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.PassportDetails
(
Pk_Passport_Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
Passport_Number VARCHAR(255),
Fk_Person_Id INT UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Person(Pk_Person_Id)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Person VALUES ('Niraj','v.a@emails.com');
INSERT INTO dbo.Person VALUES ('Vishwanath','v.v@emails.com');
INSERT INTO dbo.Person VALUES ('Chetan','c.v@emails.com');
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.PassportDetails VALUES (101, 'C3031R33', 1);
INSERT INTO dbo.PassportDetails VALUES (102, 'VRDK5695', 2);
INSERT INTO dbo.PassportDetails VALUES (103, 'A4DEK33D', 3);
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.Person
SELECT * FROM dbo.PassportDetails;
```

Notice how the `passpoerdetials` column `Fk_Person_Id` is UNIQUE.

Now in Laravel if I want to have a one-to-one realtionship, the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships), says the following:

> A one-to-one relationship is a very basic relation. For example, a
>   User model might be associated with one Phone. To define this
>   relationship, we place a phone method on the User model. The  phone
>   method should call the hasOne method and return its result:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

I was just wondering how Laravel tracks this hasOne relationship if in my migration I have not used [unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#indexes) ? This is a bit confusing for me, I just wanted to learn more about the indepth working of Laravel and hence I am asking this question. I would really appreciate if somebody could solve this mystery for me.

P.S. this not a **HOW TO** question, its more of a **WHY** question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: it doesn't.

The `hasOne` relation indicates how your data is structured (ie, `$this->hasOne('App\Phone');` indicated that your `App\Phone` table has a foreign key referring to the `User`). However, Laravel does nothing to ensure that this foreign key is unique.

If you look at [the code for the `hasOne` relation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.php), we see:

```
/**
 * Get the results of the relationship.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getResults()
{
    return $this->query->first() ?: $this->getDefaultFor($this->parent);
}
```

In other words, Laravel leaves the responsibility of ensuring uniqueness to you, and gives its result assuming this responsibility has been fulfilled (And thus the first result will be correct).